# Why if and else both condition executing same time in JavaScript | If and Else Condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement, xmlhttprequest

How If and else condition work both in JavaScript. `if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)`

I am working on php MVC project.

I created a profile edit page in background JavaScript `If` and `Else` both code executing. profile edit Successfully but else code work and it's show error "Sorry, this content isn't available right now".

why this `else` condition work??

- save in local file and run than it work :-
  [online code](https://jsfiddle.net/uttamnath/0y1aw972/20/)

`Code`

```
 document.querySelector("#Profile_Save").addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Email").value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/)) {
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").classList.remove("active_success");
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").classList.remove("active_denger");
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Save").innerHTML = "Loading...";
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Save").classList.remove("active");
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Save").disabled = true;

            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_F_Name").disabled = true;
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_L_Name").disabled = true;
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Email").disabled = true;

            var f_name = document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_F_Name").value,
                l_name = document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_L_Name").value,
                email = document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Email").value;

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "Api/ProfileEdit", true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) { // this one if executing 
                    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    if (json.Status == "Ok") {
                        window.location.href = "Profile"; // it also work 
                    } else {
                        document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").classList.remove("active_success");
                        document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").classList.add("active_denger");
                        document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").innerHTML = json.Message;
                    }
                } else { // this one else executing 
                    document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").classList.add("active_denger");
                    document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").innerHTML = "Sorry, this content isn't available right now"; // this message show 
                }
            }
            xhr.send("F_Name=" + f_name + "&L_Name=" + l_name + "&Email=" + email);
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Save").innerHTML = "Register";
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Save").classList.add("active");
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Save").disabled = false;
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_F_Name").disabled = false;
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_L_Name").disabled = false;
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Email").disabled = false;
        } else {
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").classList.add("active_denger");
            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").innerHTML = "Invalid Email Address!";
        }
    });
```

`return JSON`

```
{"Status":"Ok","Message":"Profile Edit Successfully!"}
```

`Output`

```
open profile page and 
error message:- "Sorry, this content isn't available right now"
```

[image]

help me!
Thank you!!

Comment: @nice_dev in code I commented line

Comment: `readystatechange` event fires multiple times, on the last time the else part is not reached. If you want to avoid to run the else part, listen `xhr.load` event, and check only the status.

Comment: @Teemu not work bro!

Comment: Funnily you commented before I had even written the suggestion for what to do. Anyway, see [xhr.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState). The event fires multiple times, and the `if` condition passes only the last check, all the other checks are not passed (because `xhr.readyState !== 4`), and the else block is executed instead. Why you can actually see it is unclear, as the passed check should either redirect or rewrite the message. Maybe `json.Message` contains the same text as your hard-coded error message?

Comment: `json.Message` return "Profile Edit Successfully!" not other

Comment: `xhr.readyState !== 4` I also try that but not work

Comment: @Teemu online code https://jsfiddle.net/uttamnath/0y1aw972/20/  save this code in local file and run

Comment: Yep, that was not a suggestion. If the page stays on the current location, and you see the warning the content is not available, the only chance seems to be, that the request fails on all states.

Comment: The linked fiddle gives a status code of `0`, a CORS error can be seen in the console. Is this https://riseupweb.000webhostapp.com/Android/ProfileEdit a site you control?

Comment: @Teemu this link work but online editor not allowed to load any other api and website data that why return `readyStatus 0 `and `Status 400`

Comment: @Teemu this same code work in login and registration page but not work in profile edit if you have any solution tha answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245578/discussion-between-uttam-nath-and-teemu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`onreadystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) event is fired for all the statuses mentioned in that link. In your case, you will need to check when status equals `4`(i.e, when the operation is complete and response is sent back to the browser). So, you can amend your code block like below:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {  
                    if(xhr.status == 200){
                        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                        if (json.Status == "Ok") {
                            window.location.href = "Profile";  
                        } else {
                            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").classList.remove("active_success");
                            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").classList.add("active_denger");
                            document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").innerHTML = json.Message;
                        }
                    }else{
                         document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").classList.add("active_denger");
                        document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").innerHTML = "Sorry, this content isn't available right now"; // this message show 
                    }
                    
                }
            };
```

Comment: bro same  output show it not working

Comment: @UttamNath I think my code change should fix it. Can you reproduce your error and share it via a fiddle link? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: bro check edited question  or https://jsfiddle.net/uttamnath/0y1aw972/20/

Comment: @UttamNath You didn't copy my code. No wonder it won't work. Second, it doesn't work in the link because request is blocked by CORS policy. Can you send access control headers from your backend script so that I can test it on js fiddle website?

Comment: https://riseupweb.000webhostapp.com/Android/ProfileEdit check this it work but jsfiddle.net not support.

Comment: but i got answer thank you for your response

Comment: @UttamNath Any website won't support since it is a different domain altogether. You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Comment: this same code work in login and registration page but not work in profile edit if you have any solution tha answer.

Comment: @UttamNath You will have to add that as a new question since the current thread is only limited to the issue you showed.

Comment: I add new question

Comment: @UttamNath That's good. If my current answer helped you with your initial query, can you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```js
if (xhr.readyState != 4 && xhr.status != 200) {
    document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").classList.add("active_denger");
    document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").innerHTML = "Sorry, this content isn't available right now"; // this message show 
}else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if (json.Status == "Ok") {
        window.location.href = "Profile"; // it also work 
    } else {
        document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").classList.remove("active_success");
        document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").classList.add("active_denger");
        document.querySelector("#Profile_Edit_Msg").innerHTML = json.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: bro this is `readyState` and `status`  is background URL request status.  I can't ignore that

Comment: I understood , I have updated the Answer Please check will it works or not